# Dados repetem em vez de nulo

Tags: mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gente não sei se isso é normal em sql mais vou postar aqui para tirar minha duvida. tenho uma consulta com três tabelas usando INNER JOIN, aparentemente o resultado é favorável, mas um pequeno detalhe me incomoda. veja o exemplo.
O que acontece é o seguinte na coluna codigo_loja onde é 1 não existe valores no na coluna cod_loja e coluna cod_lista, deveria me retornar null e não 3 e 1. Não sei se isso é um erro o comportamento normal. Pois onde é 1 na coluna codigo_loja eu sei que o restante não existe. Me desculpe mais sou muito novo em mysql.

```
SELECT b.cod_produto, b.nome_produto, a.cod_loja, a.cod_lista, c.codigo_loja, c.preco_produto, b.preco_produto
FROM lista_de_compras AS a
lEFT JOIN itens_lista_compras AS b ON a.cod_lista = b.cod_lista
LEFT JOIN loja_produto AS c ON b.cod_produto = c.codigo_produto
WHERE a.cod_lista =1
```

Comment: Teria que ver como vc está fazendo a consulta. Seria bom postar na pergunta.

Comment: Eu acho que sei o que está acontecendo, tenho uma tabela produtos que se relaciona com cod_produto n:n com tabela 1 e tabela2. A tabela1 com a tabela cod_produto gera cod_prodTabela1 e tabela2 com cod_produto gera cod_prodTabela2, ai eu faço um INNER JOIN COM cod_prodTabela1, cod_prodTabela2 deve ser porque as duas se relacionam com cod_produto com o mesmo id. Seria isso?